# Any way to allow multiple people to edit a coauthored, password protected workbook, at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I am currently working on a sheet that I want select people to have full access to, while everyone else without the password for the sheet cannot. I can do mediocre and overly complicated solutions with VBA and limiting visibility and whatnot, but I don't understand why I can't have multiple people edit a password protected workbook. If there is any solutions to this problem or reasons why it is caused, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking to share an Excel workbook
which is protected by password.

Microsoft calls this feature collaboration or co-authoring,
and this feature is available on recent-enough versions of Excel.

You will find more information in the following article:

- [Collaborate on Excel workbooks at the same time with co-authoring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104)
- [How to Add Co-Authors to Protected Files in Microsoft Excel](https://www.windowsdispatch.com/add-co-authors-protected-excel-files/)

Comment: When co-authoring a password protected workbook, it only allows one user at a time to edit. If another user tries to access it, it reads the following: "Someone has this workbook locked. [User] has locked this file for editing. This may happen if they're using a non-subscription version of Excel. Ask them to close the file or check it in." Both users are using a subscription version of excel. I am trying to allow both users to edit at the same time, while the workbook is password protected.

Comment: Are all the conditions from the first link exist for you?

Comment: The only condition that hasn't been met is that AutoSave is disabled, and that is because the sheet is password encrypted, which is what I want. Is there a method around this?

Comment: Microsoft says that this is required for co-authoring to work, and if workarounds exist then they are unknown to me. You might perhaps be able to do that better with Google Docs, but I'm not a user of that. For questions on Google Docs, you should ask on webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.